# ArcGIS online alternatives

Tags: software-recommendations, arcgis-platform

I am currently using ArcGIS online to create web maps and for mobile data collection; the data is stored/ created in a personal geodatabase, added to a .MXD and symbolized, etc. then pushed up to the web to create a web map.  It is hosted by ArcGIS.

I deal with a lot of users and a lot of data. This set up has had some significant limitations. For example, backing up data; because it is stored in a personal geodatabase in order to back it up I need to over write it each time.  Another limitation is that I can’t get live updates or syncs in the field again because it is stored in a personal geodatabase.

My question, what are alternatives to the system I am using?  I realize this answer may be involved so sending me in the right direction to find information or resources would be great.

This also needs to be within the ESRI environment.

Answer (score 2):

Host it yourself, rather than with ArcGIS Online. Within an Esri environment you could manage your own installation of ArcGIS for Server, which includes Portal for creating/hosting the web maps. This way you can manage your own enterprise database environment.

Comment: How difficult are ArcGIS for Server and Portal to use?

Comment: Without knowing your experience with managing enterprise software, especially GIS software, all I can say is it's easy to install and very well documented. I'd venture to say that if you can use ArcGIS Online you can use Server/Portal. The hardest part is usually database management.

Comment: So what can I do with ArcGIS for Server/Portal that I can't do with a personal geodatabase/data hosted by ArcGIS online?

Comment: The comments section on GIS SE isn't the place for extended discussion or training. I would recommend doing some basic reading here: http://server.arcgis.com/en/